# Count the occurence of a list of items in a string?

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x

How will I be able to count the number of time a list of items are repeated in a string. For example how can I search through string and check the number of times this list has been repeated in string?

```
list = ('+','-','*','/')
string = "33+33-33*33/33"
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use a name like `list`, it masks the built-in name `list` [See: [Built-in Methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html)] and that can lead to some subtle bugs.

After that, there's ways to do this. The crucial thing to have in mind is that *objects* like strings come along with a plethora of *methods* [See: [String Methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=string%20methods#string-methods)] that act on them. One of these methods is [`str.count(sub)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=string%20methods#str.count) which counts the number of times `sub` occurs in your string.

So, creating a count for every element in `lst` could be done by using a `for` loop:

```
lst = ('+','-','*','/')
string = "33+33-33*33/33"
for i in lst:
    print("Item ", i, " occured", str(string.count(i)), "times")
```

`str(string.count(i))` transforms the integer result of `string.count` to an `str` object so it can be printed by `print`.

This prints out:

```
Item  +  occured 1 times
Item  -  occured 1 times
Item  *  occured 1 times
Item  /  occured 1 times
```

After getting more accustomed to Python you could use a comprehension to create a list of the results and supply them to `print`:

```
print(*["Item {} occured {} times".format(x, string.count(x)) for x in lst], sep='\n')
```

which prints a similar result.

Finally, make sure you [read the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) available on the Python documentation website, it'll help you get acquainted with the language.

Comment: Can you can you please add a way where it shows the total time it was occurred? Also, thank you for you answer it was helpful